# Remove persistent comma in array.join after array.slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, slice

I am creating a new array of HTML elements after iterating over each element then pushing them to a new array. I then try to slice the array (which works but it inserts a comma after each item). I then use .join to remove the comma but it doesn't, why?

```
var shortReviews = [];
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('reviewContainer');
for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
shortReviews.push(elm[i].innerHTML);
}

var snappy = document.querySelector("#reviewsSnap").innerHTML = shortReviews.slice(0, 2);
snappy.join('');
```

If I call 'snappy' in console I get the array separated by commas (,) but when I use snappy.join('') I get the desired output without commas in the console but on the pages output the commas persist. What am I missing to remove the commas from snappy.join('') and have it output without comma separators?

Comment: Could you please add more information ?

Comment: You assign `shortReview.slice(0, 2)` as HTML, which will stringify the array, but you call `snappy.join()` 1. on a *different* array 2. without even assigning the result to anything.

Comment: In general, you should probably be handling DOM nodes, not HTML, since the latter is more error prone and harder to maintain. As you already see here. What's the intention - do you want to *copy* items or *move* items?

Comment: Thank you, I am creating a copy of HTML elements created using `document.createElement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain the `join()` to the sliced array:

```
document.querySelector("#reviewsSnap").innerHTML = shortReviews.slice(0, 2).join('')
```

Comment: Thank you, I was sure I tried this but evidently not.. now runs as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with HTML, consider manipulating the DOM nodes. This is cleaner and more robust solution, as HTML can be hard to manage. Here is how you can do this using the DOM API to clone the nodes and add them to a new parent:

```js
var shortReviews = [];
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('reviewContainer');
for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  //create a copy of the nodes
  shortReviews.push(elm[i].cloneNode(true));
}

var newContainer = document.querySelector("#reviewsSnap");
shortReviews
  .slice(0, 2) //take the first two
  .forEach(el => newContainer.appendChild(el)); //add them to the new container
```

```css
.reviewContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#reviewsSnap .reviewContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 1</h3>
  <p>very short review: good</p>
</div>
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 2</h3>
  <p>very short review: average</p>
</div>
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 3</h3>
  <p>very short review: bad</p>
</div>

<div id="reviewsSnap">
  <h1>Chosen reviews</h1>
</div>
```

If you want to *move* the nodes, instead of having two copies of it, you can just drop the cloning step. Each node can only have one parent, so if you add it to a new one, it will be removed from the first parent:

```js
var shortReviews = [];
var elm = document.getElementsByClassName('reviewContainer');
for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  //don't copy, take the actual nodes
  shortReviews.push(elm[i]);
}

var newContainer = document.querySelector("#reviewsSnap");
shortReviews
  .slice(0, 2) //take the first two
  .forEach(el => newContainer.appendChild(el)); //add them to the new container
```

```css
.reviewContainer {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#reviewsSnap .reviewContainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 1</h3>
  <p>very short review: good</p>
</div>
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 2</h3>
  <p>very short review: average</p>
</div>
<div class="reviewContainer">
  <h3>short review 3</h3>
  <p>very short review: bad</p>
</div>

<div id="reviewsSnap">
  <h1>Chosen reviews</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to inspect your answer closely to learn more but for context in an earlier part of the script, I already call the DOM nodes then output as HTML elements (a full list of my items). The JS above is reading from that created HTML and creating a preview from all those items taking only the for 2 from index 0. I have a feeling using a combination of your solution would be much more elegant and efficient.

Comment: For additional context, I am parsing JSON-LD data to create a dynamic list of total reviews in HTML format, then elsewhere on the page I am using the above snippet to show only a few select items. Adding .join to the chain worked perfectly, I was sure I tried this. Thank you everyone.